# AmazonSNSClient::publish response

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to use AmazonSNSClient to publish SMS text messages to a selected few phone numbers.

This is working fine, but every now and then a SMS message fails due to some error.

From the Java API, is it possible to detect that the SMS failed and also retrieve the reason for the failure?

The publish method returns a PublishResult object, but that does not contain much details.

Any way to retrieve the response details of the attempted SMS publish request with info similar to what can be found in the Cloudwatch logs?

Regards
Rolf